# arrow::read_delim_arrow() causing R session aborted when reading Large dataset (21GB) csv file in 16gb RAM system

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am trying to use **Data larger than Ram** in `R` using `arrow` package. Every time I try to `read_delim_arrow("file",delim = "|", as_data_frame = FALSE)` I get **R Session Aborted .. Fatal Error**.

Data is around **21 GB**, System RAM is **16GB**.

I was able to read this File using **Python Polars**. Data has **"|"** as **delimeter** and below is the snapshot of the data :
[image: Data Separated by "|" instead of ","]

**R** Code that I have tried which is crashing the session:

```
library(arrow)
library(duckdb)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

SF_21gb_arrow = arrow::read_delim_arrow('../Single-Family Loan Performance Data/HARP_Files/HARPLPPub.csv',
                                           as_data_frame = FALSE, delim = "|")
```

I have also tried `arrow::read_csv_arrow()` and that gives an **error** due to | delimeter.

I am not sure what else to try.

**Data Source:**

1. [fanniemae-SingleFamily-Data](https://datadynamics.fanniemae.com/data-dynamics/#/downloadLoanData/Single-Family)
2. Register/login on website which is free.
3. Download HARP Dataset (around 1-2gb)
4. Extract File (csv file around 21 gb)

Comment: `read_delim_arrow()` still reads everything into memory (as an Arrow Table if `as_data_frame = FALSE`), so if you don't have enough memory, it's still not going to work. Try `open_dataset_delim()` instead, which lets you build up an execute a query against larger-than-memory data using Arrow's Acero engine. It works very much like DBI + dbplyr, though it's not actually using SQL.

Comment: @alistaire thanks for sharing on `open_dataset_delim()` but I am not sure how to use that. I thought it was sort of replacement of what `polars in python` is with `lazy execution` but it seems with `arrow / duckdb` first I will need to create a copy of data with **partitions** and then will be able to use it.

Comment: Calling `arrow::open_*` returns a lazy object, no rows have been read into memory. Construct a dplyr sequence of commands that filters, mutates, summarizes, etc (not all actions can be done on a "lazy" arrow object), and only when you are certain that you've reduced the number of rows significantly, only then call `... %>% collect()` to pull all of the resulting data into R. If you cannot reduce the data so that it'll load into 16GB, then you cannot do it this way, you'll need to find another on-disk data processing mechanism.

Comment: You don’t necessarily _need_ to partition your dataset, though it can make querying much faster, especially if you use Parquet and choose your partitioning scheme wisely. But you can open a single file as a dataset still.

Comment: And yes, it is a lot like polars, which is also Arrow-based, though that’s leveraging a Rust implementation instead of C++.

Comment: @r2evans .. Yes even I was under this impression and hence was trying `arrow::open_*` and since my data has `delim = "|"` so I was using `open_dataset_delim()` to custom delim but that is causing **R session aborted**. Even I thought all of this operation was being done in `lazy mode` but couldn't figure our then why my session is crashing.

Comment: @alistaire thanks !! I will try it without partitioning the data then.

Comment: Your question says that you use `read_delim_arrow` and it crashes your R, is it both functions that do this? It may be that there are illegal non ASCII characters in the file. Since it is crashing R, and you claim it is not a memory-exhaustion thing, then it may be a bug. To get further help (here or on the author's issue tracker) you'll need to provide a small reproducible example that also fails with somebody else. Good luck!

Comment: It might be worth doing some naive partitioning from bash with `head` and `tail`, both because if there's a character encoding issue it will be easier to see if it's only happening on one partition, plus because it makes it easier for the query engine to split up the work. Ultimately Parquet is way, way better than flat files here, but you can take baby steps towards it.

Comment: @alistaire ohh yes I totally agree with you and I already know there is an issue of character encoding with similar data that I downloaded from the same source so that is a possibility with this dataset as well